# Can the Google Webmaster Tools API be used to automate fixing URL Page Not Found Errors?

Tags: java, api, google-search-console

If I go into Google Webmaster Tools, and click `Health->Crawl Errors`, I noticed that our site has about 1,045 Not Found errors.

Each of these errors can be fixed manually by:

1. filtering through the list to find the specified error that has been
   needs to be fixed, and clicking on it.
2. In the resulting dialog clicking the `Fetch as Google` link,
3. Clicking `Fetch`
4. And finally, clicking `submit the index` (provided there are enough fetches remaining to do so), and then marking it as `fixed`.

Since there are about 1,000 errors to fix, doing this manually seems a bit out of the question.
*(**Note:** I didn't have anything to do with it but the site was migrated before the content causing the errors.)*

I'm aware that it is possible to [retrieve a list of site errors](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#Crawl_Retrieving), but that's really only half the battle.  I looked over the APIs and didn't really find a way to use the Webmaster Tools API to mark errors as fixed.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but I solution may be to use lynx to record the commands and then to play them back using a list of the links...haven't tried it though.

Comment: If these are not pages Google should index anyway, why not use a ``robots.txt`` to keep Google away from them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking errors as "fixed" is perfectly possible with this API call:

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/urlcrawlerrorssamples/markAsFixed

So you can easily automate this by e.g. …

- fetching the crawl error sample (1000 max.)
- checking the given URLs
- marking working URLs as fixed via API

Keep in mind: Crawl error information is updated about once a day. So if there are more than 1000 errors and half of them get marked as fixed, new data that was not in the sample before will likely roll in after a day has passed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, as I just successfully tested removing all errors (4 in my case) which was possible with just a few clicks. If the errors keep reappearing you might want to take a look at where the invalid URLs are linked from: if it's internal stuff, you should fix those links, and if it's external links you should either add redirects to the updated/moved pages, or ask the external web site(s) to update their links to your site.